# SQL Query on _Sent Data View for Suppression List (5 sends in 7 days)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views, suppressionlist

I'm working in a new org where we don't have any send data. I need to set up a suppression list for any subscriber that received 5 emails in the last 7 days. I am not 100% sure if my code below will work?

```
SELECT

SubscriberKey, 

COUNT(SubscriberKey) as TotalSent FROM _Sent

WHERE EventDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

GROUP BY SubscriberKey

HAVING COUNT (SubscriberKey) > 4
```

Comment: This should work exactly as you want it to. I personally utilize `GetDate()`, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` seems like it will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue with your code, your where clause could also be something along the lines of

`WHERE eventdate > getdate() -7`